# MergeSwiftModule - Building a Swift app in Xcode 6.3 gets stuck in "Merge MyApp.swiftmodule"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

Building an app in Xcode 6.3 gets stuck for several minutes (approx. 10mins) on a step `Merge MyApp.swiftmodule`:

```
MergeSwiftModule normal x86_64 /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crbdsfrhkvpiynaffvhzzsspiels/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp.swiftmodule
```

this wasn't an issue in previous version of Xcode 6.2 and Swift 1.0.

Comment: Delete 'Derived Data', 'Reset your Simulator' and 'Clean Project'. These are the most common things and will solve your problem too.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Enabling `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` for the target seems to fix this issue.

[image: Enabling swift whole module optimization in Xcode build settings]

Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1119343#1119343

Comment: Option can be found under "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" on the Build Settings tab of your target. Thanks so much for sharing the fix!