# Xcode 6.3.1 error: Timed out waiting to acquire lock file for module 'X' where 'X' is my framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, module, xcode6.3

I have the following projects in my workspace:

1. `Common`
2. `Security` (dependent on `Common`)
3. `Data` (dependent on `Common`, `Security`, (and `CoreData`))
4. `Api` (dependent on `Common`, `Security`, `Data`)
5. `MyApp` (dependent on `Common`, `Security`, `Data`, `Api`)

All of the projects except `MyApp` are Cocoa Touch Frameworks, mostly written in Swift.

Since Xcode 6.3.1 I'm unable to compile as I'm getting the following message while building my 'Api' framework:

```
<unknown>:0: error: timed out waiting to acquire lock file for module 'Data'
~/Developer/myapp/src/Api/Api/SomeClass.swift:4:8: error: cannot load underlying module for 'Data'
import Data
       ^
```

Comment: For me, the problem went away when I removed and re-added the `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for [other issues in Xcode 6.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29767367/1161723), there seems to be [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29770363/1161723).

I have found that compiling the `Data.framework` target with the following settings solves the issue:

```
SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES
```

Although, the compilation takes longer (as Xcode pre-6.3) and I have some troubles using lldb especially in case or printing out `NSManagedObject` subclasses:

```
(lldb) po object
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'NSManagedObjectID' from AST context
```

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue in Xcode 6.3.2 and found that my problem went away when I cleaned the build folder.

Comment: This also fixed it for me. You can clean the build folder by pressing ⌥⇧⌘K.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean build folder
2. Close the project
3. Close Xcode
4. Restart the computer

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Xcode 7.2.1

> Fixed the problem where xcodebuild test timed out while waiting for iOS Simulator to boot. (24173400)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW1

Comment: Sorry, that page cannot be found.