# Xcode 6.4 hangs with "Timed out waiting to acquire lock file for module 'AVFoundation'" for Release configuration

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, avfoundation, release

While Debug configurations work for my project (Objective-C, OSX), Release configuration always hangs at the same place with the same message `Timed out waiting to acquire lock file for module 'AVFoundation'` pointing to my .m file which imports `AVFoundation` framework. 
Seems a rare bug as googling for it doesn't help a lot. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825180/xcode-6-3-1-error-timed-out-waiting-to-acquire-lock-file-for-module-x-where) concerns Swift, thus it's not applicable for my case.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? The same thing just started happening to me.

Comment: @oltman I ended up creating new schema with Debug configuration and adjusting parameters to Release configuraiton

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that your module cache is corrupted.  I had this issue and wiped it out and didn't get this error anymore.

Go to the Derived Data folder and delete the folder `ModuleCache`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your code in version control, just remove your .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace folders and check them out again. This fixed the issue for me.